# Eazfuscator.NET Embedding NLog

Tags: c#, merge, obfuscation

I am currently using Eazfuscator.NET to obfsucate and embed my libraries into one finished .exe. I am running into a problem with the NLog.dll

I have a common.dll which relies upon Nlog.dll. I can create the necessary file to add the line

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed NLog.dll", Exclude = false)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "embed Common.dll", Exclude = false)]
```

Once the application is build in release mode I can easily remove the common.dll from the output directory and everything still works. If I remove the NLog.dll the application will not crash, but it will not log anymore.

My question is does anyone have experience in merging Nlog into their project so they do not have to distrubte the dll and can have a stand alone .exe?

Comment: Sorry - I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Im looking to embed dlls into a single exe. Im also also using Eazfuscator.Net. Can u let me know how to do it?